# How to represent this concept with a set formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the first time that I post a question here, I hope it well formed.

I have a set of pairs $(a,b) \in Set$, where $Set \subset A \times B$.

Now, given an element $a' \in A$ and a function $f : A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb R$, I want to get the element $(a_s, b_s)$ where $a_s$ is such that $f(a', a_s)$ is the smallest result between all the elements in $Set$.

I'm having some problems to formalize this concept, can you help me? This is what I came up with.

$$    (a_s, b_s) = (a_i, b_i) \in Set \mid (a', a_i) = \mathop{\rm argmin}\limits_{s(a', a_i)} $$

But I don't know if this is the right way to do so.

Just to give you an example: supposing that $A \times B = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ is the sum function and we have that:

$$Set = \{(1,2) , (2,2), (3,3)\}$$

Then with $a' = 1$ the returned result is $(1,2)$ (actually $(1,2)$ is returned for any $a'$ with this toy example).

How do I formalize this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $f'$ the function that returns such a $(a,b)$ given $a'$. Then we can define it as follows:

$$f'(a')= (a,b) \leftrightarrow ((a,b) \in Set \land f(a',a) = b \land \neg \exists a'' \in A \ \exists b'' \in A \ ((a'',b'') \in Set \land f(a',a'') = b'' \land b'' < b)))$$

... I *believe* that's what you want ...